# Long SQL query - how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have an sql query that run about 24 hours.
I would like to know if there is a way to optimize it.

The Query is:

```
update r, t  set r.a1 = t.a2, r.b1 = t.b1  where r.c = t.c and r.d1 = t.d2 and r.e1 = t.e2 and r.f1 = t.f2;
```

Table r have ~2,000,000 rows and defined as:

```
Field  Type      Collation  Null  Key  Default Extra         
-----  --------  ---------  ----  ---  ------  --------------

id     int(11)   (NULL)     NO    PRI  (NULL)  auto_increment

a1     blob      (NULL)     YES        (NULL)                

e1     tinyblob  (NULL)     YES   MUL  (NULL)                

f1     int(11)   (NULL)     YES   MUL  (NULL)                

c      int(11)   (NULL)     YES   MUL  (NULL)                

b1     int(11)   (NULL)     YES   MUL  (NULL)                

d1     int(11)   (NULL)     YES   MUL  (NULL)
```

Table t have ~1,200,000 rows and defined as:

```
Field  Type      Collation  Null  Key     Default  Extra         

-----  --------  ---------  ----  ------  -------  --------------

c      int(11)   (NULL)     NO    MUL     0                      

d2     int(11)   (NULL)     NO    MUL     0                      

e2     tinyblob  (NULL)     YES   MUL     (NULL)                 

f2     int(2)    (NULL)     NO    MUL     (NULL)                 

a2     blob      (NULL)     YES           (NULL)                 

b1     int(11)   (NULL)     YES           0                      

id     int(11)   (NULL)     NO    PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment
```

I would like to know if there is a way to optimize the query?

Thanks!

Comment: `I have an sql query that run about 24 hours`: Does it take 24 hours to run? :-/

Comment: Yes :/ that's why i'm searching a way to optimize it.

Comment: Obiously something is very wrong if it takes that long. Can you put a explain statement from the query?

Comment: Can you also provide the actual create statement from the table i want to look at the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your index key should be ordered the same as your where statement.
`r` table key:

```
c,d1,e1,f1
```

and `t` table key:

```
c,d2,e2,f2
```

Do you need a key in `r` table on column `b1`?

Answer (score 0):

Your structure seems quite OK.
2M rows in not that much. Your rows may be large (with the `blobs`), but the comparison you do are only on integer values. It should be faster.

Try to run `ANALYZE`, `OPTIMIZE`, `CHECK`, `REPAIR` commands on your tables to make sure your indexes are correctly constructed.

Once this is done, you should try investigate deeper in the system.
What is slowing down the query ? It can be :

- disk I/O
- memory limit (try tuning your my.cnf, see excellent http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/ )
- CPU (seems improbable)
- network issues

Use monitoring to have data about your sql cache, memory usage etc.
It will help you diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update r left join t on r.c = t.c and r.d1 = t.d2 and r.e1 = t.e2 and r.f1 = t.f2 set r.a1 = t.a2, r.b1 = t.b1
```

Also Do some changes

- make c,d1,e1 column indexed in table r
- make c,d2,e2 column indexed in table t